# Building bibliography out-of-source: couldn't open `blx.bib`

Tags: biblatex, biber

My `Makefile`:

```
MK=lualatex -output-directory=$(TARGET)
TEX_FILE=report
TARGET=./target

$(TEX_FILE):
        $(MK) $(TEX_FILE).tex
        bibtex $(TARGET)/$(TEX_FILE)
        $(MK) $(TEX_FILE).tex
        $(MK) $(TEX_FILE).tex
```

So, on run, the command executed is: `lualatex -output-directory=./target report.tex`

In `report.tex`:

```
\usepackage[...]{biblatex}
\bibliography{report}
```

Bib(la)tex runs fine, producing `target/report-blx.bib`

But on the second run, `lualatex` complains:

```
I couldn't open database file report-blx.bib
---line 18 of file ./target/report.aux
 : \bibdata{report-blx
 :                    ,report}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `biber` as a backend to `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,...]{biblatex}
```

And use `biber` instead of `bibtex` in the Makefile:

```
biber --output_directory=$(TARGET) $(TEX_FILE)
```